# How to grant a user access to pg_cast?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to install an application and in the error logs I can see "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for table pg_cast" so im trying to grant the user access for this table. How would I go about doing this? I have tried GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON pg_cast TO mft_admin_group; and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, every user (`PUBLIC`) has access to that table:

```
\dp pg_catalog.pg_cast 
                                    Access privileges
   Schema   │  Name   │ Type  │     Access privileges     │ Column privileges │ Policies 
════════════╪═════════╪═══════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════
 pg_catalog │ pg_cast │ table │ postgres=arwdDxt/postgres↵│                   │ 
            │         │       │ =r/postgres               │                   │ 
(1 row)
```

You must either be working with a modified version, or an administrator broke your database by modifying the catalogs.